# Descargar archivo txt del servidor al cliente con PHP

Tags: php, txt

Hola a todos estoy procesando un archivo txt en el servidor usando PHP

```
$file = fopen("archivos/llaves/keyusuario.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, 'Tu llave de usuario es: 651651651651651651');
fclose($file);
```

Estoy guardando el txt en una carpeta del servidor, ahora quiero que ese txt se descargue en el navegador del cliente, he intentado los siguiente usando la ruta absoluta:

```
   $rutaArchivo = __DIR__."archivos/llaves/keyusuario.txt";
    $NombreArchivo = basename($rutaArchivo);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nombreArchivo");
    # Leer el archivo y sacarlo al navegador
    readfile($rutaArchivo);
```

Sin embargo, al terminar el procesamiento el archivo se genera con éxito en la carpeta del servidor, pero no se efectúa la descarga, agradecería mucho su ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$rutaArchivo = __DIR__."/archivos/llaves/keyusuario.txt";
$archivo = file_get_contents($rutaArchivo);
$NombreArchivo = basename($rutaArchivo);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$NombreArchivo);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archivo));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($rutaArchivo);
```

### Explicación:

- Intentabas descargar un archivo de texto como si fuera binario y tenias mal puestos los headers
- Aquí tenias un error tipográfico:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nombreArchivo")
```

pues **$nombreArchivo** no existe, era **$NombreArchivo**

Comment: Hola si efectua descarga pero me arroja estos errores

<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\nominaarchivos/timbrados/TimDetalle.txt): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\nomina\reportes_txt.php</b> on line <b>188</b><br />

Comment: el archivo está en esa ruta?  C:\xampp\htdocs\nominaarchivos/timbrados/TimDetalle.txt ?  o quizñas deberia ser esta? C:\xampp\htdocs\nomina/archivos/timbrados/TimDetalle.txt

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/nomina/archivos/timbrados/TimDetalle.txt
Esa seria la ruta correcta

Comment: vale, le he puesto una barra más a la rutaArchivo.. prueba ahora a ver

Comment: Gracias, si era un asunto de rutas, muchas gracias hermano

Comment: Perfecto!! :-) Saludos!